# Add two hours to a data taken from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So, I'm currently trying to add two hours to my timestamp type data in phpMyAdmin.
The function is the below one,

```php
public function collection()   
{  return Booking::select('id','place_id', 'payer_name', 'user_fullname', 'user_email', 'user_phone', 'user_no_of_guest', 'user_no_of_babies', 'user_checkin',
         'user_checkout', 'is_approved', 'user_promo', 'user_payment_type', 'user_booking_tracking_id', 'created_at','paid_ammount')->get();
}
```

The database is like this and the data's name is "created_at".

Is there a way to add two hours directly when collection?
Or do I have to think of something else?

Comment: Note that there is no data in PHPMyAdmin; it's merely an administrative tool. You can directly add two hours to each timestamp using the datetime functions discussed in the manual.

Comment: My purpose is to add those two hours only for this function, as I don't need to add two hours when retrieving data later on.

Comment: Select raw `created_at + INTERVAL 2 HOUR` instead of the column.

Comment: If the function is relevant to the problem, I suggest you add the text of the fiunction to the body of the question. Around here, pictures are rarely welcome or helpful.

Comment: @Akina, do I just add it after created_at like, 'created at' + 'INTERVAL 2 HOUR', ? or somehow else? not really sure how to approach it

Comment: Study https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the bellow code, using the help of people in the comments.

```
return Booking::select(
        'id',
        'place_id',
        'payer_name',
        'user_fullname',
        'user_email',
        'user_phone',
        'user_no_of_guest',
        'user_no_of_babies',
        'user_checkin',
        'user_checkout',
        'is_approved',
        'user_promo',
        'user_payment_type',
        'user_booking_tracking_id',
        Booking::raw('(created_at +  INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS created_at'),
        'paid_ammount'
    )->get();
```